# Service issue with IBM Watson Natural Language Understanding

Tags: nlp, websphere, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-nlu

While using IBM Watson Natural Language Understanding, I got this issue: Service returned status code 500: cannot analyze: downstream issue.

Comment: You need to provide more details, like what is the code that raised this issue? What are you trying to obtain? What other solutions that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I got to know that IBM Watson has regular maintenance at that time, hece, the service was returning server generic error.

thanks;